# Comparison test for trig series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have following series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(3n)}{n^4} $$

Then I use comparison test, compare them to
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4} $$

And conclude they converge.

However, I have this task marked as mistake "You can do comparison test only on positive number series". So are there alternative ways to prove convergence?
I have tried symbolab but it also uses comparison test

Comment: @imranfat: thats in itself doesn't prove convergence.

Comment: @Martin would you mind explaining in wat sense my comment is different from Jose's answer?

Comment: @imranfat: your comment seems to imply that you can do comparison directly. I don't think you can avoid going through absolute convergence. For instance if you take $a_n=(-1)^n\frac{\pi^4}{90}$, then $-\sum_n\tfrac1{n^4}\leq \sum_{n=1}^ma_n\leq\sum_n\tfrac1{n^4}$ for all $m$, and still the series does not converge.

Comment: Interesting observation. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can compare the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left\lvert\frac{\sin(3 n)}{n^4}\right\rvert$ with $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^4}$ and deduce from this that the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(3 n)}{n^4}$ converges absolutely. Therefore, it converges.

Comment: How do I argument this to my professor who marked this as error?

Comment: You don't. Your argument is wrong and I did **not** use it. Unlike you, I applied the comparaison test to two series of non-negative numbers.

Answer (score 2):

We can't use direct comparison test directly since the $a_n$ term of the given series oscillates.

What we can use is the [absolute convergence criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence) that is

$$\sum |a_n|<\infty \implies \sum a_n<\infty$$

and in this case if we consider

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left\lvert\frac{\sin(3 n)}{n^4}\right\rvert$$

we can apply direct comparison test on that since $|a_n| \ge 0$ and we obtain that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left\lvert\frac{\sin(3 n)}{n^4}\right\rvert \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4}$$

thus $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left\lvert\frac{\sin(3 n)}{n^4}\right\rvert$ converges and by absolute convergence criterion also the original series converges.

To summarize the steps for the proof are

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4}<\infty \stackrel{D.C.T.}\implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left\lvert\frac{\sin(3 n)}{n^4}\right\rvert <\infty \stackrel{Abs.C.C.}\implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(3 n)}{n^4} <\infty$$